# How to register a variable in ansible based on another variable?

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of servers on different subnets. I want to configure a NFS mountpoint for each one, selecting which NFS server based on which subnet they're on. I can easily do it with multiple code blocks, each having a different `when` condition, but with more than just a couple of networks, this results in an awful lot of code duplication:

```
- name: mount /home for 192.168.1.0
  mount:
    path: /home
    src: nfsserver-1.domain.net:/vol/home
    fstype: nfs
    opts: tcp,hard,intr,bg
    state: mounted
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '192.168.1.0'

- name: mount /home for 192.168.2.0
  mount:
    path: /home
    src: nfsserver-2.domain.net:/vol/home
    fstype: nfs
    opts: tcp,hard,intr,bg
    state: mounted
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '192.168.2.0'
```

How can I register a variable, based on another variable? When I try the code block below, it fails because multiple tasks register `detected_nfs_server` and conflict with each other. (The variable doesn't just get registered when the `when` block is applicable).

```
- name: detected_nfs_server initialize to blank
  shell: echo ''
  register: detected_nfs_server
  changed_when: False

- name: detected_nfs_server nfsserver-1.domain.net
  shell: echo 'nfsserver-1.domain.net'
  register: detected_nfs_server
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '192.168.1.0'
  changed_when: False

- name: detected_nfs_server nfsserver-2.domain.net
  shell: echo 'nfsserver-2.domain.net'
  register: detected_nfs_server
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '192.168.2.0'
  changed_when: False

- name: Fail detected_nfs_server
  fail:
    msg: "'domain.net' not in detected_nfs_server.stdout"
  when: "'domain.net' not in detected_nfs_server.stdout"

- name: mount /home
  mount:
    path: /home
    src: {{ detected_nfs_server.stdout }}:/vol/home
    fstype: nfs
    opts: tcp,hard,intr,bg
    state: mounted
```

So far, the best solution I've found is to run a shell script as shown below. This works fine, but it requires using shell script instead of doing variable manipulation inside of ansible. Is there a good way to register a variable in ansible, based on another variable, rather than depending on shell script?

```
- name: detect_nfs_server
  shell: if [ '{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}' = '192.168.1.0' ] ; then echo 'nfsserver-1.domain.net' ; elif [ '{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}' = '192.168.2.0' ] ; then echo 'nfsserver-2.domain.net' ; else echo 'domain not detected' ; fi
  register: detected_nfs_server
  changed_when: False

- name: fail if domain not detected
  fail:
    msg: 'domain not detected'
  when: detected_domain.stdout == 'domain not detected'

- name: mount /home
  mount:
    path: /home
    src: {{ detected_nfs_server.stdout }}:/vol/home
    fstype: nfs
    opts: tcp,hard,intr,bg
    state: mounted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more options. It's possible to use a dictionary (stored in group_vars ?). For example

```
vars:
  detected_nfs_server:
    192.168.1.0: nfsserver-1.domain.net
    192.168.2.0: nfsserver-2.domain.net
    192.168.3.0: nfsserver-3.domain.net
tasks:
- name: mount /home
  mount:
    path: /home
    src: "{{ detected_nfs_server[ansible_default_ipv4.network] }}:/vol/home"
    fstype: nfs
    opts: tcp,hard,intr,bg
    state: mounted
```

Next option is to generate the server's name. For example

```
- set_fact:
    detected_nfs_server: "{{ 'nfsserver-' ~
                              address.split('.').2 ~
                             '.domain.net' }}"
- name: mount /home
  mount:
    path: /home
    src: "{{ detected_nfs_server }}:/vol/home"
    fstype: nfs
    opts: tcp,hard,intr,bg
    state: mounted
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used `set_fact` to set `detected_nfs_server`, and then used `detected_nfs_server[ansible_default_ipv4.network]` to extract the desired value based on the `network` variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one option might be to have a var file loaded with each of the NFS servers on different subnets. Then you can reference the vars.

```
nfs1 = 192.168.1.x
nfs2 = 192.168.2.x
nfs3 = 192.168.3.x
```

Comment: If I set those variables, is there some way I can actually make them useful? It seems, any code I could write that would reference those variables, I could just substitute the IP addresses in for those variables, it hasn't solved the actual problem of code repetition. Not that I can think of.

Comment: This guide goes more in depth about registering and using variables.
https://www.mydailytutorials.com/ansible-register-variables/

in short you can register the output of a command as a variable, then re-use it in a play.